# Can't get Crashlytics to Process dSYMs

Tags: xcode, firebase, crashlytics

I've been using Crashlytics for some years quite successfully. This was with the web interface for processing symbols. However, I cannot seem to get the processing of symbols to work such that the web page stops showing that required symbols are missing. These are the specific approaches I have taken within Xcode and the terminal.

First, as part of the `Build Phases` tab, I have added the following as a `Run Script`
`"${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/run" -gsp "${PROJECT_DIR}/Resources/GoogleService-Info.plist"`
This does not cause any errors or warnings but also doesn't seem to do anything.

Second, since the above doesn't do anything, I use the terminal to manually upload the symbols. To make things easier I get the `dSYMs` folder for the build and put it directly into the `Pods/FirebaseCrashlytics` directory. I do the same with the `GoogleService-Info.plist` file. I then execute the following command:

`sudo ./upload-symbols -gsp GoogleService-Info.plist -p ios dSYMs`

The process runs and the output shows that symbols are being successfully uploaded. There are no errors thrown with every line being a success. Checking the dashboard, however, and the required symbols remain the same and nothing is processed. I know processing can take some time but it stays this way for days. When I have uploaded via the web page in the past, it was a matter of minutes. Of course there is nothing on the web page to indicate that it has received and is processing anything so I have no idea what's happening.

What am I missing here and how can I get symbols to process again?

Comment: Is your app migrated from Fabric or onboarded fresh in Firebase?

Comment: @OlegKodysh - Firebase has now processed those symbols. I didn't do anything additional. It just started working after some days.